# Unable to launch any application on my anaconda platform

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, spyder

Greetings: please neither jupyterlab, jupyternotebook, spyder none of them are working, it keeps giving me bunch of dependency errors and i don't even understand the errors: below are some when i launch spyder

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 128, in main
from spyder.config.manager import CONF
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/config/manager.py", line 22, in
from spyder.config.main import CONF_VERSION, DEFAULTS, NAME_MAP
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/config/main.py", line 21, in
from spyder.config.appearance import APPEARANCE
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/config/appearance.py", line 15, in
from spyder.plugins.help.utils.sphinxify import CSS_PATH
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/help/utils/sphinxify.py", line 34, in
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/**init**.py", line 12, in
from .environment import Environment
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 25, in
from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 3, in
from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401
File "/Users/mac/Public/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 13, in
from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/Users/mac/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/markupsafe/**init**.py)

PS. anyone who understands what's happening should please help me i need to submit a project today

i already uninstalled and installed new anaconda, i tried downgrading it, i tried importing some of the dependency manually. yet all show to no avail

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To fix this, please open a terminal and run the command `rm -Rf /Users/mac/.local/lib/python3.9`. That will remove that directory, which contains Python packages that are interfering with the Anaconda ones.